# How to copy rows and paste selected rows in same table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, copy-paste

Here i want to copy rows and must be able to paste the rows below

i want to add functionality to my table as in this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Lfjuapub/1/

Please find my fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/zrcoLyeg/6/

```
 <table id="tblColumnSchedule" class="display nowrap table table-hover table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
       <tr>
          <th data-sort-initial="true" data-toggle="true">User</th>
          <th data-hide="phone, tablet">Label</th>
          <th data-hide="phone, tablet">Profile</th>
          <th data-hide="phone, tablet">Location</th>
          <th data-hide="phone, tablet">Start</th>
          <th data-hide="phone, tablet">End </th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>s1</td>
        <td>w10x22</td>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>20</td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
       <td>s2</td>
        <td>w10x24</td>
        <td>A1.1</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>40</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

For example if i select 2 rows cloumns like Location,   Start , End,
i must be able to paste selected rows in 3 rows.
Any help is highly appiceable.

Comment: Really not a very well detailed explanation for a complex behavior. Can interpret this several different ways

Comment: what interpret can you explain me very well before downvoting think correctly what others are trying to say and if you know answer or else give sugesstion

Comment: It is up to you to explain your issue properly. Not for us to have to ask multiple clarification questions. Explain by example

Comment: i am explaining my issue not as per your issue

Comment: Just telling you what is needed to get help as in [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: without understanding the question how is it possible for two persons to answer my question

Comment: Then you have your solutions don't you? Easy to write vague answers that don't translate directly into code. More difficult when expectations are not clear

Comment: yes their are some inteligent person who gives answers to questions without wasting time in comment and do you feel using an external library like handsontable is a vague answer

Answer (score 1):

Try using an external library like [handsontable](https://handsontable.com/examples?manual-resize&manual-move&conditional-formatting&context-menu&filters&dropdown-menu&headers).

Comment: Do you have any similar fiddle??

Comment: @Priya Their examples https://handsontable.com/examples.html?headers themselves have a link to "Edit in Fiddle"